# JQuery only working in IE

Tags: jquery

This code works in IE10 but doesn't work in Chrome, Firefox, or Opera. I don't understand why this is the case, I tried to download the JQuery-2.1.1.js file and that did not work either.

All this code should do is toggle a simple div with a form in it.

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>Welcome</title>
<script>
    $(Document).ready(function (e) {
        $("#Login").click(function () {
            $("#Partial").toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Is there a specific reason the code will not work in the other browsers?

Comment: When something only works in IE, then it really isn't working at all, is it? `$(Document)` should be `$(document)`. JS is case-sensitive.

Comment: first thing I would try is making the D in Document lower case. Second thing I would do is edit your question to include the HTML as well, could be you are going after the wrong element, or spelled it wrong, or something simple like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be because of the capital `D` in `document`. Try this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $("#Login").click(function () {
            $("#Partial").toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```